# What is the Euclidian diameter of the following 'metric ball' in $[0,1)$?

Tags: metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, dynamical-systems, circles

Given an $m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$, define the map $f\colon[0,1)\to[0,1)$ by $f(x):=mx\mod1$. Using this map, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define the metric $$d_n(x,y):=\max_{0\leq i\leq n-1}\min\{|f^{i}(x)-f^{i}(y)|,1-|f^{i}(x)-f^{i}(y)|\}$$ on $[0,1)$. Given $a\in[0,1)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, what is the (Euclidian) diameter of the ball (or actually the interval) $B_{d_n}(a,\varepsilon)$? For simplicity, it is okay to make assumptions on $\varepsilon$ (e.g. $\varepsilon<1/m$, if needed).

Note that $d_{n}$ measures the maximum distance between the first $n$ $f$-iterates of $x$ and $y$.

EDIT: I read somewhere that $$B_{d_n}(x,\varepsilon)=B_d(x,\varepsilon/m^{n-1}),$$ where $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1-|x-y|\}$ and $0<\varepsilon<1/2$, but I don't see why this is true. This would imply that the Euclidian diameter of $B_{d_n}(x,\varepsilon)$ is $2\varepsilon/m^{n-1}$.

Comment: Have you verified that this is actually a metric? It isn't obvious at a glance.

Comment: See this [book](https://www.fisica.net/ebooks/caos/Brin%20ans%20Stuck%20-%20%20Introduction%20to%20Dynamical%20Systems.pdf), page 4 and 37 combined.

Comment: Since you used the [tag:circles] tag, I guess that you're familiar with the identification of $[0,1)$ and the unit circle in the complex plane for purposes like this. On the unit circle, $f$ corresponds to $z \mapsto z^m$, and $d$ is the arc-length distance divided by $2\pi$. Now look at the case $a = 1$, and then note that the general case follows by rotation (if $w = \zeta\cdot z$, then $w^i = \zeta^i\cdot z^i$, and thus $d_n(w,z) = d_n(\zeta,1)$).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response! Even in the case $a=1$ I don't really understand how the 'shortest arc length' (SAL) translates to the Euclidian distance. The SAL metric on $S^{1}$ has the property that it 'flips' at angle $\pi$. The Euclidian metric does not have this property.

Comment: True, @Jens. (You didn't `@`-ping me, so I wasn't notified of your comment and only now happened to see it by chance.) But once you know how the $d_n$-balls look on the circle, you can find how they look in $[0,1)$ by cutting the circle at $1$. For that, the value of $a$ is relevant. If the $d_n$-ball on the circle (which is an open arc) doesn't contain $1$, you get one interval in $[0,1)$, with the same diameter as the arc (since we divided the length by $2\pi$), and if it contains $1$ [but isn't the entire circle], you get the union of two disjoint intervals, $[0,u) \cup (v,1)$.

Comment: The Euclidean diameter of that is $1$, regardless of which values $0 < u < v < 1$ have.