# Property of a metric on $[0,1)$

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, circles, absolute-value

This question is related to a question I posted earlier today (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410987/what-is-the-euclidian-diameter-of-the-following-metric-ball-in-0-1?noredirect=1#comment7015529_3410987), this metric gives me nightmares), but I think it is easier to answer this one. Let $m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$ and consider the map $f\colon[0,1)\to[0,1)$ defined by $f(x):=mx\mod 1$. Also consider the metric $d(x,y):=\min\{|x-y|,1-|x-y|\}$ on $[0,1)$. I think that the following statement is true, but I don't know how to prove it:

> Suppose that $d(x,y)\leq\frac{1}{2m}$. Then $$d(f^{k}(x),f^{k}(y))=m^kd(x,y)$$ for all $0\leq k\leq m$.

I think that I know how to prove the statement for the cases $|x-y|\leq\frac{1}{2}$: In this case we have $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, so $$d(f^{k}(x),f^{k}(y))=|kx-ky\mod1|\overset{?}{=}k|x-y|.$$ However, I'm not sure about the step with the questionmark. For the case $|x-y|\geq\frac{1}{2}$, I have no idea. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I also know that this metric can be viewed as the metric on the unit circle that measures the shortest arc length between two points (divided by $2\pi$). However, this only gives me some intuition.

Comment: Doesn't this metric kind of turn $[0, 1)$ into $S^1$?

Comment: yeh, see my edit on the post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one can reduce your question to the case $|x - y| \leq 1/2$ as follows. If $|x - y| > 1/2$ then there exists an isometry of $[0,1)$, namely $h: z \mapsto z - y \text{ mod } 1$, mapping $y$ to $0$. But then, $|h(x) - h(y)| \leq 1/2$ (otherwise swap $x$ and $y$), so we can apply your result to $h(x)$ and $h(y)$.

Edit: Your original statement had a mistake. A complete solution to a corrected version could be outlined as follows. First, apply an isometry to $[0, 1)$ such that $x = 0$ and $y \leq 1/(2m)$ (thinking of $S^1$ helps). Then compute
$$d(f(x), f(y)) = md(x,y).$$
Similarly,
$$d(f^2(x), f^2(y)) = md(f(x), f(y)) = m^2d(x, y).$$
Proceeding similarly,
$$d(f^k(x), f^k(y)) = md(f^{k-1}(x), f^{k-1}(y)) = \dots = m^kd(x,y).$$

Comment: Are you sure that we have $|h(x)-h(y)|\leq1/2$? Since $|h(x)-h(y)|=|(x-y\mod1)-(y-y\mod1)|=|x-y|>1/2$?

Comment: If not, then instead letting $h(z) = z-x$ fixes it. This is because $|h(x) - h(y)| = (x-y) \text{ mod } 1$, and not $|x-y|$ as you claim.

Comment: So, to be clear, I do not need the assumption $d(x,y)\leq1/2m$?

Comment: Yes you do, but only in order to apply what you already proved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why my proof worked? Because I can counterexample the statement $$d(f^k(x),f^k(y))=|kx\mod1-ky\mod1|=k|x-y|.$$ For example, suppose that $k=3$, $x=3/10$ and $y=4/10$. Then $|x-y|\leq1/2$ and $$k|x-y|=3/10$$ and $$|kx\mod 1-ky\mod1|=|9/10\mod1-12/10\mod1|=|9/10-2/10|=7/10.$$

Comment: @Jens You are right, the step is wrong. See my edited answer (and also your edited question): we in fact instead have $d(f^k(x), f^k(y)) = m^kd(x,y)$ instead of $kd(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. I see what I did wrong. So thanks for the correction! I have one more question: Why can we take out the $m$? To be more precise, why do we have $$|mx\mod1,my\mod1|=m|x-y|?$$

Comment: This is because $my \leq 1/2 < 1$, so $my \text{ mod } 1 = my$, and $x = 0$.